# playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Host system is missing dependencies？？

Tags: playwright

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyrzN.png)

```
root@f083f367b874:/app# vim test.py
root@f083f367b874:/app# python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    run(playwright)
  File "test.py", line 3, in run
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 9449, in launch
    firefoxUserPrefs=mapping.to_impl(firefox_user_prefs),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 103, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_type.py", line 90, in launch
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_type.py", line 86, in launch
    return from_channel(await self._channel.send("launch", params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 36, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 54, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Host system is missing dependencies!

  Missing libraries are:
      libnss3.so
      libnssutil3.so
      libsmime3.so
      libnspr4.so
      libatk-1.0.so.0
      libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0
      libcups.so.2
      libdrm.so.2
      libdbus-1.so.3
      libxkbcommon.so.0
      libXcomposite.so.1
      libXdamage.so.1
      libXfixes.so.3
      libXrandr.so.2
      libgbm.so.1
      libasound.so.2
      libatspi.so.0
      libxshmfence.so.1
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This means that your operating system dependencies are not installed. You can install them by executing `playwright install-deps` after you have installed Playwright. See here for the docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#install-system-dependencies

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Playwright for Python, run: `playwright install-deps`

If you're using vanilla JS Playwright, run: `npx playwright install-deps`

Looks like you're using the Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending

```
# { pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "kubelt";

  nativeBuildInputs = [ pkg-config ];
  
  buildInputs = [
    clojure
    clojure-lsp
    babashka
    leiningen
    nodejs-16_x
    jdk
    docker
    google-chrome
    chromedriver
    act
    docker
    rustup
    libuuid
    act
    wayland
    google-chrome-dev
    firefox-bin
]

  APPEND_LIBRARY_PATH = "${lib.makeLibraryPath [ libGL libuuid wayland google-chrome-dev firefox-bin]}";


  shellHook = ''
    LD=$CC
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$APPEND_LIBRARY_PATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  '';

}
```